the TerraformAsset constructor to process the Path as a Token As Opposed to one of the AssetType
{
      "module": "module.cmp1_test",
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "netbox_device",
      "name": "device",
      "provider": "provider.netbox",
      "instances": [
        {
          "schema_version": 0,
          "attributes": {
            "face": 0,
            "id": "2828",
            "name": "cmp1",
            "position": 15,
            "rack": "111",
            "role": "cmp",
            "serial": "",
            "site": "example.site",
            "status": "Planned",
            "tenant": "VPC",
            "type": "Generic-1U"
          },
          "private": "bnVsbA=="
        }
      ]
    }

